# Rendering Mutiple HTML Pages in sharepoint with a time gap

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, html

I'm relatively quite new to SharePoint (2007) and I currently have a page veiwer webpart rendering one HTML file from my c:\ on to an internal moss site on the default page. I need help on the possiblity of having a flip option between mutiple HTMLs files on a moss page with a certain time lag. Meaning, if I have file x.html currently being displayed, I want the another y.html after 30secs or so which is shared in the same location. I'm not sure if I can do that with page veiwer webpart.

Regards... Thota

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this with jQuery and iframes.  Instead of the page viewer web part, use a content editor web part to put some custom HTML code on the page.  In that HTML code, display your first page in an iframe and then use jQuery to cycle/load your pages on the time interval.